# Two input fields in JSF form should map to one entity

Tags: jsf, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to save a new entity called `Benchmark` based on input from a JSF form.

I'm unsure of how to proceed. In `Benchmark` there is a relationship attribute called `article`. `article` is already in the database, but i need to add a reference to it for the new `Benchmark` entity that I wan't to insert. There is a unique id for `Article` called `AID` but this is not something the user knows about. The user uses the `Article` fields `Art` and `Supplier` to identify a unique `Article` entity/database table row. But I'm unsure how to use that input information to set the `article` field in the `Benchmark` entity. Usually I would set a converter for the testfield which converts the string value to the right entity type (as I do for Antigen/target), but I can't see how I would do that here since there are two input fields.

Any suggestions/hints on how to proceed?

This is (roughly) my `Benchmark` entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Benchmark.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Benchmark b"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Benchmark.countTotal", query = "SELECT COUNT(b) FROM Benchmark b")})
public class Benchmark implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String ALL = "Benchmark.findAll";
    public static final String COUNT = "Benchmark.countTotal";        
    @Id
    private Integer ID;

    @Column(name="ba_type")
    private String type;

    @JoinColumn(name = "target", referencedColumnName = "PID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private MuxProtein target;    

    @JoinColumn(name = "benchmark_assay", referencedColumnName = "AID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Article article;    

    @JoinColumn(name = "sample_type", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private SampleType sampleType;        

    @JoinColumn(name = "target", insertable=false, updatable=false,referencedColumnName = "PID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private MuxProtein proteinPID;    
...
}
```

And this is the form:

```
<h:form id="addDilForm">
    <p:panelGrid >
        <f:facet name="header" >
            <p:row><p:column colspan="2">New benchmark</p:column></p:row>
        </f:facet>

        <p:row> 
            <p:column colspan="1">
                <h:outputLabel>Sample</h:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{benchController.benchy.sampleType}" converter="SampleTypeConverter">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{SampleTypeController.samples}" var="samp" itemLabel="#{samp.name}" itemValue="#{samp}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="1">
                <h:outputLabel>Antigen</h:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
            <p:column >
                <p:inputText value="#{benchController.benchy.target}" converter="MuxProteinConverter"  />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
            <p:column rowspan="2">
                <h:outputLabel>Benchmark assay</h:outputLabel>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputLabel value="Articlenumber " /><p:inputText />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column><h:outputLabel value="Supplier " /><p:selectOneMenu ><f:selectItems value="#{supplier.suppliers}" var="supp" itemLabel="#{supp.supplier}" /></p:selectOneMenu></p:column>
        </p:row>                 

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="2">
                    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{dilution.save()}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

And my `Supplier` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Supplier implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "SID")
    private Short sid;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Supplier")
    private String supplier;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "supplierSID")
    private List<Article> articleList;
...
}
```

And my `Article` entity:

```
@Entity(name="MuxArticle")
public class Article implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "AID")
    private Integer aid;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Art")
    private String art;

    @Column(name = "Price")
    private String price;

    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_SID", referencedColumnName = "SID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Supplier supplierSID;
...
}
```

Comment: Please add the supplier entity

Comment: Where is / what's àrt?

Comment: Added it. Also added the Article entity, where art is a field.